# Remove Emojis from String Rust

Tags: rust, emoji

How would I remove emojis from a string like `"⚡hel✅lo"`?

I know you'd need to make use of `Regex` and a few other stuff but I'm not sure how to write the syntax and replace everything in the `string`.

Thanks, help is really appreciated .

Comment: The first step is to define what exactly you mean by "emoji". It's likely you don't want to remove all characters that have the "Emoji" property in the Unicode character database, since that would include characters like # and *. A good approximation may be using the "Emoji_Presentation" property, which is set for all characters that default to emoji presentation rather than text presentation.

Comment: I guess the main question here is: What is your goal? Why do you want to remove emojis from a string?

Comment: The first question I'd have here is related to yours @SvenMarnach, "How would you do this in *any* programming language?"  Whitelist-based?  Blacklist-based?  Looking up a standard for what's in the "Emoji" space versus other characters?  The majority of the problem has nothing to do with Rust.

Comment: It looks like the [`unicode_segmentation`](https://unicode-rs.github.io/unicode-segmentation/unicode_segmentation/trait.UnicodeSegmentation.html#tymethod.graphemes) crate can find grapheme clusters. Then it's just a matter of determining whether a given grapheme is an emoji

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I took some time to figure out, but here's the solution

````rs
/// Removes all emojis from a string **(retains chinese characters)**
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `string` - String with emojis
///
/// # Returns
///
/// * `String` - De-emojified string
///
/// # Examples
///
/// ```
///
/// // Remove all emojis from this string
/// let demojified_string = demoji(String::from("⚡hel✅lo"))
/// // Output: `hello`
/// ```
pub fn demoji(string: String) -> String {
    let regex = Regex::new(concat!(
        "[",
        "\u{01F600}-\u{01F64F}", // emoticons
        "\u{01F300}-\u{01F5FF}", // symbols & pictographs
        "\u{01F680}-\u{01F6FF}", // transport & map symbols
        "\u{01F1E0}-\u{01F1FF}", // flags (iOS)
        "\u{002702}-\u{0027B0}",
        "\u{0024C2}-\u{01F251}",
        "]+",
    ))
    .unwrap();

    regex.replace_all(&string, "").to_string()
}
````

Comment: I would assume there's a typo here, because "\u{0024C2}-\u{01F251}" seems to select everything between "circled latin capital letter m" (Ⓜ) in the third section of the BMP and "Circled Ideograph Accept" (), which covers 3/4th of the BMP and pretty much the entirety of the SMP.

Comment: I would also recommend following Sven Marnach's line of questioning & suggestions, because this seems ahcky in the extreme, and quite prone to falling over itself.

Comment: A small tip on writing documentation examples. Instead of `"// Output: 'hello'"`, write `assert_eq!(demojified, "hello");` and it doubles as a unit-test!

Comment: To note, this appears to also be deleting Simplified Chinese hieroglyphs from strings. I don't think you'd usually consider them emojis.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same question myself now, and came up with a more reliable way to perform this than with a regex.

You can't reliably use regex or otherwise filter out individual `char`s for this, as there are some that don't count as emoji by themselves but may be part of an emoji.

For example, if you put the symbols  and then  together one right after another, they immediately collapse into  and turn into the flag of Great Britain, which is considered an emoji. But it's unlikely you consider those two individual characters themselves as emojis.

My method works by iterating over individual Unicode grapheme clusters, and then filtering out those that happen to be full emojis.

This relies on [`unicode_segmentation`](https://crates.io/crates/unicode-segmentation) and [`emojis`](https://crates.io/crates/emojis) Rust crates for the two steps.

```rust
pub fn remove_emoji(string: &str) -> String {
    use unicode_segmentation::UnicodeSegmentation;
    let graphemes = string.graphemes(true);

    let is_not_emoji = |x: &&str| emojis::get(x).is_none();

    graphemes.filter(is_not_emoji).collect()
}
```